# Can't resize maximized frameless window

Tags: windows-10, resizing

My text editor (vile.exe) has no menu bar.  In Win 10 (mine, anyway), it also has no title bar. Sometimes, when moving this window, I inadvertently cause it to maximize.  Once thus, I haven't found a way to change the size back to what it was.  In particular, 'size' is grayed-out in the ALT-SPACE pop-up menu.

How might I undo the 'maximization' of this window?  Thanks

Comment: Right-click on its icon in the taskbar, then click Restore?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is a title bar.  On the maximized window, it just slips behind the Windows Task Bar, which I put at the top of the screen.

So, using ALT-SPACE 'Move', and arrow keys, I can move the title bar down to where I can get at it, and restore the original size.